# Checking if a variable is there but empty

Tags: javascript

A field is considered "empty" if one of the following conditions are true:

- The value is `null`.
- The value is an empty string (`""` or `''`).
- The value is an empty array (`[]`).
- The value is `undefined`

Values such as `false` or `0` must not be considered empty.

Here's my current code:

```
var isValueEmpty = 
    value === null ||
    value === "" ||
    (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0)
```

Any way to further improve this (speed, readability)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Maybe elaborate with a use-case or rationale why you think this code is necessary? I think you'll find there will be more feedback on your use-case. The code you provided does exactly what it should do - but if I spot this during a review I'd have it reworked such that the whole thing is gone.

Comment: It's for a database schema data validation ODM, where "required" in the validation schema means there must be a value (string, number, array) but it must also not be an empty value

Comment: I'm not sure why or how a use case would be helpful to anyone for a simple question like this. I just want to check for the following conditions in a fast and readable way.

Answer (score 2):

You could go for:

```
var isValueEmpty = !value && value !== undefined
```

but this would also return `true` for `false`, `0` and `NaN`.

Comment: That's right, i want it to return true for false, 0 and NaN

Thanks!